# How to install and configure Apache, PHP and MySQL in a docker container

Tags: php, mysql, apache, docker

I have CentOS installed on VirtualBox and I have installed Docker on CentOS.
I want to install Apache, PHP and MySQL in a docker container.
My aim is to run a few PHP scripts which connect to MySQL database and perform certain queries.
I want to do all of this inside a docker container and run the PHP files in the browser from localhost.

My idea is that:

1. pull a base OS image from docker like Ubuntu or CentOS
2. run this CentOS image as a container
3. enter the container in interactive terminal mode
4. install Apache, PHP and MySQL in this container
5. perform configurations
6. create a PHP file
7. run the PHP file in browser from localhost

PS: I specifically need PHP 5.6 version as I have already developed code to connect to the MySQL database from PHP 5.6
The mysql_connect function and other mysql_ functions are deprecated in PHP 7

Can anyone guide me to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: This is awfully broad and you really shouldn't install both PHP and MySQL in the same container. Additionally, you should upgrade PHP because using the `mysql_*` functions are dangerous and easily hacked.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: You could have a look at [ddev](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which does most of that for you